# How to disable an image which is in the Kendo Grid based on Boolean value?

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Actually my requirement is to disable an image which is having a click event inside the kendo grid.

Can any one help me?

Here I attached a picture:

[image: pic]

Comment: attach code and show us what have you tried

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for it Just I wrote a method and called it in template(in the kendo grid). The method will return just image and image with click action depending on the condition.

```
 function imageDisable() {
        var Role1 = ('@checkForRole1' === 'True' ? true : false);
        var Role2 = ('@checkForRole2' === 'True' ? true : false)
        var x = '<img src="../Content/Images/edit-page.png" MetaDataTitle="FillerMetalsPopUp" WmSppWldrId=\"#=WeldSppWelderId#\" onClick="PopupForMetaData(this);" style="cursor:pointer;"/>';
        var y = '<img src="../Content/Images/edit-page.png" />';
        if ((Role2 === true && Role1 === true) || Role2 === true) {
            return x;
        } else if (Role1 === true) {
            return y;
        }
    }
```